# не правильно удаляются элементы из Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

первое удаление происходит нормально, после же происходит измнение 0 элемента при изменении любого из элементов тоесть заполняются одновременно два элемента в массивах, но изменяется только 1 элемент, и только 1 элемент должен быть изменен в массивах, также при удалении изменного элемента(второго по счету), приложение крашится изза ошибочного индекса, при попытке изменения элемента в массивах.
Не понимаю в чем проблема.
Код(старый):

```
class recy : RecyclerView.Adapter<recy.MyViewHolder>() {
    private var num = 1
    private var x = 0
    private var array = mutableListOf<LinearLayout>()
    private var checkarr = mutableListOf<Boolean>(false)
    private var editarr = mutableListOf<String>("")
    private var checkarrl = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var editarrl = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var check = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var edit = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var bool = true
    private var booll = false
    fun plusnum(){
        checkarr.add(false)
        editarr.add("")
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val layout = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layoutrecyclerlist)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, i: Int) {
        holder.apply {
            if (bool) {
                bool = false
                if (checkarr.size != 0) {
                    layout.checkBox4.isChecked = checkarr[i]
                    layout.edittext4.setText(editarr[i])
                    if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                        layout.background = ColorDrawable(R.color.black_overlay)
                }
                else{
                    num = 0
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
            if (checkarr.size != 0&&booll) {
                layout.checkBox4.isChecked = checkarr[i]
                layout.edittext4.setText(editarr[i])
                x+=1
                if (checkarr.size == x){
                    x = 0
                    booll = false
                }
                if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                    layout.background = ColorDrawable(R.color.black_overlay)
            }
            else
                x= 0
            layout.checkBox4.setOnClickListener{
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
                println(editarr)
                println(checkarr)
            }
            layout.edittext4.addTextChangedListener {
                println(i)
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                println(editarr)
                println(checkarr)
            }
            layout.checkBox4.setOnClickListener {
                if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                    layout.background = ColorDrawable(R.color.black_overlay)
                else
                    layout.background = null
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
            }
            layout.button4.setOnClickListener {
                booll = true
                println(i)
                checkarr.removeAt(i)
                editarr.removeAt(i)
                println(checkarr)
                println(editarr)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return checkarr.size

    }
}
```

Код(новый):

```
class recy : RecyclerView.Adapter<recy.MyViewHolder>() {
    private var num = 1
    private var x = 0
    private var array = mutableListOf<LinearLayout>()
    private var checkarr = mutableListOf<Boolean>(false)
    private var editarr = mutableListOf<String>("")
    private var checkarrl = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var editarrl = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var check = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var edit = mutableListOf<String>()
    var pos : ((muttai0) -> Unit)? = null
    var del : ((muttai0) -> Unit)? = null
    private var bool = true
    private var booll = false
    fun update(x : MutableList<Boolean>,y : MutableList<String>){
        checkarr = x
        editarr = y
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val layout = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layoutrecyclerlist)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") i: Int) {
        holder.apply {
            var text = object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(
                    s: CharSequence?,
                    start: Int,
                    count: Int,
                    after: Int
                ) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    println(i)
                    pos?.invoke(muttai0(layout.checkBox4.isChecked, s.toString(),i))
                    println(editarr)
                    println(checkarr)
                }
            }
            layout.checkBox4.isChecked = checkarr[i]
            layout.edittext4.setText(editarr[i])
            if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                layout.background = ColorDrawable(R.color.black_overlay)
            layout.checkBox4.setOnClickListener{
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
                println(editarr)
                println(checkarr)
            }
            layout.edittext4.removeTextChangedListener(text)
            layout.edittext4.addTextChangedListener(text)
            layout.checkBox4.setOnClickListener {
                if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                    layout.background = ColorDrawable(R.color.black_overlay)
                else
                    layout.background = null
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
            }
            layout.button4.setOnClickListener {
                del?.invoke(muttai0(i = i))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return checkarr.size

    }
}
```

Код(новыйv2)

```
class recyclerviewedit : RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerviewedit.MyViewHolder>() {
    private var num = 1
    private var x = 0
    private var array = mutableListOf<LinearLayout>()
    private var checkarr = mutableListOf<Boolean>(false)
    private var editarr = mutableListOf<String>("")
    private var checkarrl = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var editarrl = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var check = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var edit = mutableListOf<String>()
    private var bool = true
    private var booll = false
    private var layouts = mutableListOf<LinearLayout>()
    var save : ((list) -> Unit)? = null
    var del : ((position) -> Unit)? = null
    var textc = 0
    var texthintc = 0
    var tasks = 0
    var taskscomlete = 0
    fun savelist(){
        check.clear()
        edit.clear()
        for (i in 0..num-1){
            check.add(checkarr[i])
            edit.add(editarr[i])
        }
        println("lists:")
        println(check)
        println(edit)
        save?.invoke(list(namelist = "",listbool = check,liststr = edit))
    }
    fun getcheck(): MutableList<Boolean> {
        return checkarr
    }
    fun getedit(): MutableList<String> {
        return editarr
    }
    fun listf(booll : MutableList<Boolean>,str : MutableList<String>,y : Int,c : Int,z : Int,e : Int){
        bool = true
        checkarr = booll
        editarr = str
        textc = y
        texthintc = c
        tasks = z
        taskscomlete = e
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    fun gettasks(): String{
        var x = ""
        layouts.forEach {
            x+=it.edittext4.text.toString()+"\n"
        }
        x.substring(0,x.length-1)
        return x
    }
    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val layout = itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layoutrecyclerlist)
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.layoutlist, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") i: Int) {
        holder.apply {
            layouts.add(layout)
            layout.edittext4.setTextColor(textc)
            layout.edittext4.setHintTextColor(texthintc)
            layout.setBackgroundColor(tasks)
            var text = object : TextWatcher{
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    editarr[i] = layouts[i].edittext4.text.toString()
                    checkarr[i] = layouts[i].checkBox4.isChecked
                    println(editarr)
                    println(checkarr)
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

                }

            }
            if (bool) {
                bool = false
                if (checkarr.size != 0) {
                    layout.checkBox4.isChecked = checkarr[i]
                    layout.edittext4.setText(editarr[i])
                    if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                        layout.setBackgroundColor(taskscomlete)
                }
            }
            layout.checkBox4.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
                println(editarr)
                println(checkarr)
            }
            layout.edittext4.addTextChangedListener (text)
            layout.checkBox4.setOnClickListener {
                if (layout.checkBox4.isChecked)
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(taskscomlete)
                else
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(tasks)
                checkarr[i] = layout.checkBox4.isChecked
                editarr[i] = layout.edittext4.text.toString()
            }
            layout.button4.setOnClickListener {
                booll = true
                del?.invoke(position(i))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
         return checkarr.size

    }
}
```

активити:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var x = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    private var y = mutableListOf<String>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerviewedit).adapter = recy()
        findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerviewedit).layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        var a = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerviewedit).adapter as recy
        var recyclerview = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerviewedit)
        recyclerview.adapter = recyclerviewedit()
        recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        var recadapter = recyclerview.adapter as recyclerviewedit
        recadapter.save = {
            if (noteorlist&&list){
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    listrep.update(list(id = objectlist.id,namelist = binding.nameplaintext.text.toString(), listbool = it.listbool, liststr = it.liststr))

                }
            }
            else{
                if (binding.nameplaintext.text.toString() != "" || it.listbool != mutableListOf(false) && it.liststr != mutableListOf("")) {
                    var list = list(
                        namelist = binding.nameplaintext.text.toString(),
                        listbool = it.listbool,
                        liststr = it.liststr
                    )
                    when (screen) {
                        "deleted" -> {
                            list = list(
                                namelist = binding.nameplaintext.text.toString(),
                                listbool = it.listbool,
                                liststr = it.liststr,
                                deleted = true
                            )
                        }
                        "archived" -> {
                            list = list(
                                namelist = binding.nameplaintext.text.toString(),
                                listbool = it.listbool,
                                liststr = it.liststr,
                                archived = true
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        listrep.insert(list)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        recadapter.del = {
            var bool = recadapter.getcheck()
            bool.removeAt(it.x)
            var str = recadapter.getedit()
            str.removeAt(it.x)
            recadapter.listf(bool,str,file.getedittext(),file.getedithinttext(),file.getedittasks(),file.getedittaskscomlete())
        }
        binding.addchecheckbox.setOnClickListener {
            var bool = recadapter.getcheck()
            bool.add(false)
            var str = recadapter.getedit()
            str.add("")
            recadapter.listf(bool,str,file.getedittext(),file.getedithinttext(),file.getedittasks(),file.getedittaskscomlete())
        }
    }
}
```

как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никогда не используйте `viewholder`, в которых будет `if` без `else`, иначе получите кучу "`не тех данных`". Вообще не понятно что выделаете и что делают ваши переменные. Распишите подробно, либо поставьте комментарии в коде.

Comment: @Daichi вы так не продвинетесь, если будете продолжать усложнять написанный неправильно адаптер. Вам надо его целиком удалить и начать заново, исходя из идеи, что логики в адаптере быть не должно. В адаптер нужно передавать данные извне и уведомлять о событиях в нём того, кто снаружи (события вида нажата кнопка, введён текст, переключен чекбокс). Тот, кто снаружи адаптера должен принять событие, пересобрать данные и отправить их обратно в адаптер для отображения.

Comment: какую логику вы имеете ввиду добавление элементов в массывы или присвоение уже сохраненных данных новым элементам, если одно из этих двух, то я не очень представляю как это сделать вне адаптера

Comment: Я чуть-чуть написал в ответ как надо бы начать переписывать. Но целиком писать мне лень, да и времени нет)

Answer (score 0):

Если совсем кратко, то надо адаптеры примерно так использовать:

1. В адаптер передаётся список/массив данных для отображения и адаптер уведомляется о том, что надо перерисоваться.
2. Адаптер данные отображает и уведомляет владельца о событиях (клики, ввод текста, переключение чекбоксов etc).
3. Владелец адаптера по полученным из адаптера событиям меняет данные для отображения.
4. Далее повторяются пункты 1-3 до бесконечности.

В коде это, примерно, может так выглядеть:

Объявляем класс, содержащий какие-то данные для отображения:

```
data class UiData(val id: Int, val text: String, val isChecked: Boolean,)
```

Составляем список данных для отображения:

```
val dataToShow = listOf(UiData(0, "some text", true), UiData(1, "some text 1", false))
```

Передаём данные в адаптер и уведомляем его об изменениях:

```
val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as MyAdapter
adapter.setData(dataToShow)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

В адаптере отображаем данные (в onBindViewHolder) не забыв убрать слушатели событий перед этим (!)

```
val textWatcher = object TextWatcher { /*тут методы TextWatcher-а*/ }

holder.editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckChangedListener(null)

val itemToShow = dataToShowInAdapter[position]
holder.editText.setText(itemToShow.text)
holder.checkBox.setText(itemToShow.text)
```

И вешаем нужные слушатели событий: (в onBindViewHolder)

```
holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckChangedListener(/*тут слушатель*/)
```

Дальше мне лень писать, тут сложно)

Comment: пожалуйста распишите как именно, мне нужно переписать адаптер потому что по вашему коду я не понял, я переписал так что-бы работа с массивами происходила только в активити, но это не помогло та же проблема, я обновил код и добавил код активити просмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: также хочу дополнить описание проблемы, забыл написмать, на каком то рандомном моменте приложение крашится, ошибка не совсем рандомно это я не понимаю алгоритм вылетов, ошибка:     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6 , индекс и размер массива не имеет значение оно может вылететь и с индексом 2 и 2

Comment: Попробуйте словами описать что экран делать должен. Типа нажал на кнопку - добавился элемент в список например

Comment: Крашится т.к. вы из адаптера адаптер меняете. Так не стоит делать)

Comment: есоли вы имеете ввиду notifyDataSetChanged(), который был в layout.button4.setOnClickListener, в последних строках адаптера, то эту ошибку я просто не заметил, но щас исправил и проверил, краш не починился

Comment: после нажатия на кнопку, должен создаваться элемент, это происходит нормально, дальше нужна функция удаления элемента из ресайклвью по кнопке из элемента, я прикрепил скриншот в тему, что бы вы понял как это выглядит и о чем я говорю

Comment: я также изменил добавление и удаление как вы говорили(из фрагмента), не помогло, добавил новую версию